# Undocumented functions should not be viewable/displayed in the list - Issue document only for documented entities

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen, chm

```
class EXAMPLE{
    public func1()
    private func2()
    func3()
}
```

I have checked for documented entities only. I have documentation for func1 and func3 but no documentation for func2. I have

```
EXTRACT_ALL            = NO
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = NO
EXTRACT_STATIC         = NO
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = NO
```

But after the documentation is generated I still see the signature of func2 without hyperlink.

Does anyone know a way to show only those functions explicitly documented?

Answer (score 2):

You must turn on the EXTRACT_PRIVATE flag. 
As func2() is private and the EXTRACT_PRIVATE flag instructs Doxygen to ignore the private even if they are documented.

Answer (score 2):

if you only want to include documented methods in your final result that set

HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS = YES

there is  also a flag to hide undocumented classes: HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES